# Cambiar CSS paginator bootstrap (links) Laravel

Tags: css, laravel, bootstrap-4

Al utilizar `{{ $x->links() }}` de Laravel me hace la paginación            correctamente, pero me añade en mi código html el siguiente formato:

```
<ul class="pagination">
<li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="&laquo; Previous">
<span class="page-link" aria-hidden="true">&lsaquo;</span>
</li>

<li class="page-item active" aria-current="page"><span class="page-link">1</span></li>
<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="x?page=2">2</a></li>

<li class="page-item">
<a class="page-link" href="x=2" rel="next" aria-label="Next &raquo;">&rsaquo;</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Mi aplica correctamente el CSS, menos donde se hace uso de `aria-disabled= y aria-current=` ¿Sabéis como puedo solucionar esto? Mi CSS es el siguiente:

```
.pagination li {
  margin-left: .25rem;
  margin-right: .25rem;
}

.pagination li a {
  border-radius: .25rem;
  border: none;
  min-width: 2.25rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #4f5464;
}

.pagination li.active a,
.pagination li a:hover {
  background-color: #1d97c9 !important;
  color: #fff;
}

.pagination [aria-current] {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #cc33ff;
}
```

Aquí al final ya intente introducir `[aria-current]`

Os pongo un ejemplo de como se me ve:

[image: paginator]

Y así es como me gustaría que se viera:

[image: Paginador en HTML5 y CSS]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas pisar los estilos aplicados a los selectores `.page-link` y `.page-item.active .page-link`.

#### Ejemplo:

```css
.pagination li {
  margin-left: .25rem;
  margin-right: .25rem;
}

.pagination li .page-link {
  border-radius: .25rem;
  border: none;
  min-width: 2.25rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #4f5464;
}

.pagination li.active .page-link,
.pagination li .page-link:hover {
  background-color: #1d97c9;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="page-item disabled" aria-disabled="true" aria-label="&laquo; Previous">
    <span class="page-link" aria-hidden="true">&lsaquo;</span>
  </li>

  <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page"><span class="page-link">1</span></li>
  <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="x?page=2">2</a></li>

  <li class="page-item">
    <a class="page-link" href="x=2" rel="next" aria-label="Next &raquo;">&rsaquo;</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Solucionado!!! Me ha funcionado correctamente. Muchas gracias!